# how to get data from a checked ListViewBox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listview, listbox, checkedlistbox

Hi :) basically i have a Checked ListViewBox (i selected "checked = true" in the properties section). I need to be able to get data from the checked items/rows in the listViewBox to calculate a total price in a text box. I have a combo box where you can select what file you want to be displayed in the ListViewBox (so the lvwbox can alternate between 3 different files but i can solve this using a simple If Statement - *If cboDate = "....." Then.....etc.* so it's not a problem)

I'll post a screenshot of my form on here so it makes more sense but basically, i need to code something that lets me select multiple items in the ListViewBox and then displays a total price based on those selections (btw each item in the Box has a different price)

The file names are JuneEvent, JulyEvent and AugEvent and each one has several record fields which are ClassID, ClassDescripion, ClassTime and ClassPrice.

I've been stuck on this for ages can someone please help me! thanks lol :P

p.s
Currently the only code i have on the form is to display a certain file in the ListViewBox based what is selected in the combo box...

[Click here to see the screenshot of program form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHYzg.png)

[Here is the form in action](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fkyk3.png)  - ignore the table on the right hand side - i'll deal with that later

EDIT: RECENT CODE:

```
Private Sub lvwEvents_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles lvwEvents.ItemChecked
        Dim totalAmt As Double = 0
        For Each lv As ListViewItem In lvwEvents.Items
            If lv.Checked = True Then
                totalAmt += JuneEvent.ClassPrice
            End If
        Next
        txtPrice.Text = FormatNumber(totalAmt, 2)
End Sub
```

Comment: Start to work with the ItemChecked event, then use the CheckedItems collection to loop over the items checked, extract the column with the price, sum it to a running total, display the total. Add a bit of search on these topics and you will 'un-stuck' very quickly

Comment: Have a look here [ask]  and here [mcve] to find out how to post questions with all the information we need.  Posting images of your program aren't usually very helpful.  It's much better to include enough code that we can duplicate your problem and help answer it.

Comment: I think the problem is with the _JuneEvent.ClassPrice_. Show us how you initiate and assign the value.

Answer (score 1):

My friend managed to fix it for me: this is the final result:

```
  Private Sub lvwEvents_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles lvwEvents.ItemChecked
    Dim totalAmt As Double = 0
    'check what items are checked in list view
    For Each lv As ListViewItem In lvwEvents.Items
        If lv.Checked = True Then
            'add checked items value to total
            totalAmt += Double.Parse(lv.SubItems(4).Text.Substring(1))
        End If
    Next
    'display total price
    txtPrice.Text = FormatNumber(totalAmt, 2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a code posted for us to study, I'll just add here the code that will do what you need to do. I hope you can use it as your reference.

```
     Private Sub ListView1_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles ListView1.ItemChecked
        Dim totalAmt As Double = 0 
        For Each lv As ListViewItem In ListView1.Items
            If lv.Checked = True Then
                totalAmt += Val(lv.Text)
            End If
        Next
        lblLabelForYourTotalAmt.Text = FormatNumber(totalAmt,2)
     End Sub
```

I assume here that *ListView1.Items(0).Text* is the amount to be summed.

Comment: Thanks but it still doesn't get the price from the form :/ :S and i tried it your way and this way:  Private Sub lvwEvents_ItemChecked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs) Handles lvwEvents.ItemChecked
        Dim totalAmt As Double = 0
        For Each lv As ListViewItem In lvwEvents.Items
            If lv.Checked = True Then
                totalAmt += JuneEvent.ClassPrice
            End If
        Next
        txtPrice.Text = FormatNumber(totalAmt, 2)
    End Sub     - but nothing puts anything in the total box (just 0.00)

Comment: Kindly add that code in your question so we can better understand what you were doing. :) it's kinda hard to read also in comment.

Comment: sorry i don't know how to do this (i'm new here) i've added the code to the main question and its still come up the same (all jumbled with no new lines etc. - what do i do??

Comment: Can you show us what is JuneEvent.ClassPrice in ur code?